# SSRS Report Row Visibility showing detail records when it shouldn't

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is structured like:

Org
   Project
       Version (multiple)

Org and Project are groups. I set the row visibility for Version to Hide and toggled by Project. I set the row visibility for Project to Hide and toggled by Org. When I open the report I see the Orgs but also the Version (detail) records. If I expand an Org the Projects show up and the Detail disappears (correctly).

Why do the Version/Detail rows show when all the Projects are hidden?

SSRS 2012 with VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

After writing this I went back and looked at it and realized I should have been setting Group properties, not Row Properties. Duh. It's been a while since I used SSRS...